# Crash launching a sub activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am crashing trying to launch a sub-activity.  I have a small app to demonstrate the problem.  The main part of the app is a list view, and when you click on an item in the list view it is supposed to launch an activity which brings up a gallery view.  The app crashes before onCreate() is called for the gallery view class, so I suspect I have omitted some necessary thing in the xml for the activity description.

manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="randombrand.ListGallery"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

        <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".ListGallery">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <activity android:label="Manual Top" android:name=".TestGallery">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

        </application>
    </manifest>
```

java:

```
    public class ListGallery extends ListActivity
    {
        private static final String[] astrMainMenu = { "List Item 1", "List Item 2" };


        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main,
                    astrMainMenu));

            ListView lView = getListView();
            lView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent();

            intent.setClass(this, TestGallery.class);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

stack trace for crash when I call startActivity():

```
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2417  
ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2512   
ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 119 
ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1863  
ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
Looper.loop() line: 123 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4363    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 860  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 618 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

thanks in advance,

Jay

Comment: Why are you using that intent-filter on your TestGallery activity?

Comment: Doesn't the code change you suggest:

 Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestGallery.class);

do the same thing as my existing code (although more efficiently)?

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(this, TestGallery.class);

As far as my choice of intent-filter…  What intent-filter would be appropriate for what I am trying to do?

Comment: You don't appear to need an intent-filter for what you're trying to do.  From what you've described, the entry for that activity in my manifest would be just <activity android:name=".TestGallery" />

Comment: I removed the intent filters and changed the intent constructor. I still get an identical crash.

Comment: Could you post the code for your TestGallery class?

Comment: The problem was the INTENT filters in the xml.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should create `Intent` using next code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestGallery.class);
```

Its not enough to just specify class name, your also need to specify package name where this class is located. In the above code example package name is taken from `this` (`this` is `Context`, and package name is taken via `Context.getPackageName()`).

**P.S.** Note that under "package" I do not mean java's package, I mean Android's package. The one that is specified in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.